# Bootstrap carousel - loading animation when active image is loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a `Bootstrap carousel` and an invisible div with a loading gif that I want to show while a big image is loading. I'd like to show this div only when I change the active image on the carousel and this image is still loading.
I've already got the HTML and CSS working, I just need an help with `jQuery`.

I fetch the images links from Imgur and then build the *carousel-items* that I need with jQuery and append them on the carousel container.
I then attached to the carousel event `slide.bs.carousel` a function that shows me the loader. and this works

BUT BUT BUT

1. I'm worried that the loader will show for few milliseconds even if the image is already loaded/cached. How can I prevent this? How can I know if the image that is becoming active is already loaded? Do I really need to worry about this or I just leave it like this?).

I then want to hide the loader when the active image is ready, and I've done this:

```
$('.carousel-item img').each(function(){
    $(this).on('load', function(){
    $("#loader_container").css("visibility","hidden");
  });
});
```

2. But it doesn't work. Seems like this load even keeps firing until
   all the images of the whole carousel are loaded, and also somehow
   the loader doesn't hide in the end, and this is the issue n.2.

Probably I'm approaching this wrong. 
Is issue n.1 really a problem? And how can I solve issue n.2?
Thank you!

EDIT 1:

I tried to do this but still doesn't work. When I slide to the next slide I see that the image is already loaded, then the loader appears and doesn't go away anymore.

```
     $(".carousel-item img").each(function(index){
        $(this).on('slid.bs.carousel', function(){
          $("#loader_container").css("visibility","visible");
        });
        $(this).on('load', function(){
          $("#loader_container").css("visibility","hidden");
        });
        $(this).attr("src",links[index]);
      });
```

EDIT 2:

Also, it seems like the browser try to load all the images as soon as possible, even the ones that are not displayed/are not active items.
I'd like to load the images only if the user goes to that slide and makes the item active.

EDIT 3:

I've found a library name jquery.unveil.js that seems like it does exactly what I need and is super easy to use... but somehow it doesn't work. 
Maybe AngularJS can help me? Anyone know how can I modify my code to do this with angular? Like using `ngui-in-view`?

Comment: Try using fadeIn() and fadeOut()

Comment: that could be a solution for issue n.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with lazy loader, here the code:

```
$(".carousel.lazy").on("slide.bs.carousel", function(ev) {
var lazy;
lazy = $(ev.relatedTarget).find("img[data-src]");
if(lazy.length > 0){

  $("#loader_container").css("visibility","visible");
  $(".carousel-item img").on("load",function(){
    $("#loader_container").css("visibility","hidden");
  });

  lazy.attr("src", lazy.data('src'));
  lazy.removeAttr("data-src");
}});
```

I needed that `if(lazy.length > 0)` because once I did a full round of the carousel and all the images where loaded, somehow the loader would show up and never go away. I tried with `if(img.complete)` but it didn't work so I used that technique.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.carousel-item img').each(function(){
    $(this).on('slid.bs.carousel', function(){
      $("#loader_container").css("display","none");
    });
  });
```

You can use the slide.bs.carousel and slid.bs.carousel instead